# Shuffling An Array List

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to shuffle an `ArrayList` of cards. I have a method in my deck class that looks like this:

```
public void shuffle(Array <Deck1> deck){
    deckOne.shuffle();
}
```

In my main game class I initialized the variables and want to shuffle the deck. Here is what I have:

```
public class MainGame {
    private Deck1 deckOne;

    public MainGame() {
        deckOne = new Deck1();

        deckOne.shuffle(x);
    }
}
```

I then go and print out the cards. The issue I'm having is  what to pass in to the `deckOne.shuffle(x);` line. Where `x` is what I need to pass in.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm coding in LibJDX.

I tried the `shuffle` method shown below and it also did not work.

```
public void shuffle(){
    deckOne.shuffle();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Like I said. "The issue i'm having is what to pass in the the "deckOne.shuffle(x);" line. Where "x" is what I need to pass in."

Comment: You have to pass an instance of `Array <Deck1>` I can't tell you where you get it from because you don't show your definition of `Deck1`

Comment: @Faro I have tried deckOne.shuffle(Deck1); and it does not work

Comment: You probably want to shuffle an array of cards.  In real life you shuffle a deck, but a deck is made up of 52 cards.  You don't understand your problem or abstraction well enough.  A card will have a suit (heart, club, diamond, spade) and a value (ace, 2, 3, etc.).

Comment: @duffymo I'm not sure what you mean by "You don't understand your problem or abstraction well enough". I'm simply asking what to pass in the `deckOne.shuffle();` line. My deck(s) only have 20 cards and they are made up of my own stats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Faro and duffymo already stated your question is not very clear -- or at least we do not understand it very well. I think the problem here may be that you're using an inappropriate design for your domain. In particular, why do you need to pass anything into the `shuffle` method on the `Deck` class? Shouldn't it be able to shuffle its own internal cards?

In my mind a design like the following makes more sense:

```
class Card {
   private int value;
   private String suit; // Or an enum, whatever you prefer

   ... constructor/getters/setters ...
}

class Deck {
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;

    ... constructor to initialize cards ...

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }
}

public class MainGame {
    private Deck deckOne;

    public MainGame() {
        deckOne = new Deck();
        deckOne.shuffle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do an easy one: a `List` of integers.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Demonstration of shuffle feature
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 1/12/2016
 * Time: 11:05 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747973/shuffling-an-array-list?noredirect=1#comment57242343_34747973
 */
public class ShuffleDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 );
        System.out.println(String.format("before shuffle: %s", numbers));
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);
        System.out.println(String.format("after  shuffle: %s", numbers));
    }
}
```

How would you change this so it was a `List` of `Card`, which has a suit and a face value?  Would a `Deck` having a `List<Card>` make sense?